# Can I add my own code in the code generated by ride.py?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

I am creating a scenario in Ride.py
While ride.py gives me the code generated by the included Selenium2Library commands, I wish to do some additional code for the application testing. Can I add my own code?
Will normal selenium/java/c#/python code work ?

I am new and I could not find anything online

```
Select Tab
    [Arguments]    ${tabName}
    ${selectTabWait} =    Set Selenium Timeout    10 seconds
    Set Selenium Implicit Wait    ${selectTabWait}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    id:foo
    Select Frame    id:foo
    Wait Until Element is Visible    //span[contains(text(),'${tabName}')]
    Click Element    //span[contains(text(),'${tabName}')]
    Unselect Frame
```

Can I add any selenium code in above statements?

Comment: Just one acronym - RTM http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extending-robot-framework

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot add any selenium code in the above statements, nor code from any other programming language.

However, you can add any robot keywords you want, and those keywords can run any selenium code. So, if you want to do something that isn't already supported by an existing keyword, you can create your own keywords.